# Loop through node children in rss feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

So I am not really sure how to do this and it seems pretty pretty trivial but I am getting an rss feed back and all I want to do is loop through a set of each elements that have children but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the values. My xml looks like this:

```
<rss>
    <item>
        <title>Test</title>
        <picture>Test</picture>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Test 1</title>
        <picture>Test 1</picture>
    </item>
</rss>
```

My jquery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var FEED_URL = "myFeedUrl";
    $.ajax({
        url : FEED_URL,
        type : "GET",
        success : function(xml) {
            var item = $(xml).find('item').children();
            $(item).children().each(function() {
                var title = $(item).children().find('title').text();
                            //do something
            });

        }
    });
});
```

I am able to loop through it and get the 'item' element. But I want to loop through the children elements but I am not sure how to get the actual value! I thought I could do find such as:

```
var title = $(item).children().find('title').text();
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
        var item = $(xml).find('item');
        $(item).each(function(index, value) {
            var title = $(value).children('title').text();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the call to children.

```
var item = $(xml).find('item');
item.each(function() {
    var title = $(item).find('title').text();
    //do something
});
```